# Deploy Rails4 with ckeditor to Heroku , failed with time-out assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I wrote a rails4 app and deployed to heroku, and everything is ok until I add `gem ckeditor` and wanna implement this wysiwyg editor.  when I run

`git push heroku master`

it takes me massive time at this step

`Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline

       Running: rake assets:precompile`

even more , finally I get this error:

`! Timed out compiling Ruby/Rails app (15 minutes)
! See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#time-limit`

seems this editor is too heavy to compile.

I have searched for the solution , like this two tips-pages

[Page I](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/270)

[Page II](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/119)

After I did like those:

```
  #  config/initializers/ckeditor.rb:
  Ckeditor.setup do |config|
    config.assets = ["ckeditor/ckeditor.js"]
  end
```

still got the same time-out error.

Sigh for wasting so many time waiting that precompile error.

just wondering how to disabe unnecessary packages like some language-packages , plugins exactly.

BTW, things could be done with assets:precompile locally.

Comment: for ckeditor gem, they given some steps to solve assets problem https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor#usage-with-rails-4-assets

Comment: I know and try those steps, but not work for me . still time-out error

Comment: try this in application.rb config.assets.precompile += Ckeditor.assets and rake assets:precompile:all

Comment: U mean I compile locally then push to heroku?  I did it in local successfully  without that line in application.rb .  Just let heroku compile for me instead of doing it in local.

Comment: why can't you precompile locally in production mode and push in heroku, using this command RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile:all

Comment: uh...I am right doing in this way locally, just want to know why the other way can not work and how to make that way work.

Comment: @Danpe  still not yet, and I have been using another [editor](https://github.com/HackerWins/summernote),

Answer (score 2):

So I finally solved it by doing the following:

1. Adding `config.assets.precompile += Ckeditor.assets` to `application.rb`
2. Added `gem 'turbo-sprockets-rails3'` to my Gemfile under `:assets` group.
3. Removed unused Gems from Gemfile.
4. `Bundle Install`
5. Removed the following lines from `active_admin.js.coffee`:

   ```
   //= require active_admin/base
   //= require ckeditor/override
   //= require ckeditor/init
   ```
6. Pushed to Heroku.
7. Added the 3 lines  back.
8. Pushed again.

Now everything works because most of the assets have been recompiled before pushing with `ckeditor`.

Answer (score 1):

Add `config.assets.precompile += Ckeditor.assets` in your application.rb file

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same situation. In my case, I temporarily removed ckeditor-related-js from `application.js`. Specifically, these two lines:

```
//= require ckeditor/override
//= require ckeditor/init
```

Then, I deployed my application to Heroku. If ckeditor is the root cause, the deployment should be successful.

Next, I reverted the previous commit and deployed again. This deployment should take shorter time because only changed assets will be precompiled.

In my case, I succeeded this heavy deployment. I wish this procedure would help you.

Answer (score 0):

Solution that really works:

1) Add to your root .js file (like `application.js`):

```
//= require ckeditor/override`
//= require ckeditor/init`
```

2) Create new .rake task in this code to your "lib" folder:

```
namespace :ckeditor do
  desc 'Create nondigest versions of some ckeditor assets (e.g. moono skin png)'
  task :create_nondigest_assets do
    fingerprint = /\-[0-9a-f]{32}\./
    for file in Dir['public/assets/ckeditor/contents-*.css', 'public/assets/ckeditor/skins/moono/*.png']
      next unless file =~ fingerprint
      nondigest = file.sub fingerprint, '.' # contents-0d8ffa186a00f5063461bc0ba0d96087.css => contents.css
      FileUtils.cp file, nondigest, verbose: true
    end
  end
end

# auto run ckeditor:create_nondigest_assets after assets:precompile
Rake::Task['assets:precompile'].enhance do
  Rake::Task['ckeditor:create_nondigest_assets'].invoke
end
```

to copy non-digest copies of CKeditor files after assets:precompile on deploying

Code taken there: https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Steps from https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor worked for me;

Load editor from gem vendor
Include ckeditor javascripts in your app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

Include ckeditor javascripts in your app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require ckeditor/init
```

Make sure that you put it before:

```
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score -1):

But if you don't want to use that Gem then you can also do that in an easy way.

```
rake assets:precompile      (at local)
commit your public/assets   (you do not need to push that public/assets at github).
git push heroku master
```